# After pandas groupby, column names are not at the same level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using pandas to groupby my data.

However, I got the dataframe which columns are not at the same line.  not sure how to fix it.
my code is

```
    df["real_date"]=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
    df.groupby(['real_date']).mean()
```

However, I got the new dataframe which columns are not in the same line. Not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: You have an index. Either use `.reset_index()` at the end, or state `as_index=False`: df.groupby(['real_date'], as_index=False).mean()